# Opengl ES not rendering the video in nexus device

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I was rendering the local video and 3 remote videos on the screen - It has no issues.
Added another step of accessing a live streaming from one of the url.
May be due to too many contents or too many resource being used - Two of my remote video rendering has started impacting. It was not able to render and display is blank.

Any suggestions/recommendations to address this problem?

It is working fine for most of the devices except it has issue with Nexus.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the body of your code. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Okay will try to dump the code soon. Some of the additional things I'd like to mention :A. local and 3 videos are the related to gpu processing and B. loading the remote video from the url is cpu processing and no rendering is involved here.